# PHP 8: how to declare an associative array in attributes

Tags: php, attributes, php-8

I have this controller annotation :

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="list", defaults={"_format": "html", "tag": ""})
 */
```

I want to convert it to PHP 8 attributes. But how to pass the associative array of the `defaults` parameter? This works:

```
#[Route("/", name: "list", defaults: [])]
```

But this isn't:

```
#[Route("/", name: "list", defaults: ["_format": "html", "tag": ""])]
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, found the answer while writing the question, that was quite obvious. We have to use the PHP standard syntax:

```
#[Route("/", name: "list", defaults: ["_format" => "html", "tag" => ""])]
```